Update subset of json elements in PostgreSQL's jsonb
In one of my tables (let call it Table) I have jsonb column(Column), value in it has following json:
{
   "Id": 1,
   "Elements": 
   [
      {
         "ElementId": 1,
         "IsEnabled": true
      },
      {
         "ElementId": 2,
         "IsEnabled": false
      }
   ]
}

Now I'd like to enable elements by providing Ids to the query (I cannot use index, those Ids might have gaps). How to do that in PostreSQL?
edit
I was able to select altered one array element with this part of the query:
select jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.Elements[*] ?(@.ElementId<>1)') || '{"ElementId": 1, "IsEnabled": false, "ProductName": "Name"}'::jsonb
from table

from here, I'd need help with how to preserve outer parts of json (so Id and Elements nodes)
edit 2
Ok, I did update only the elements part with jsonb_set. Thanks for help

This question is similar to: postgresql complex jsonb update. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it is different because I have additional element in json (added) and my array is a named object. in linked question there is an example with flat array

Not sure what you mean by "I have additional element in json (added)" - you only want to enable existing elements, right? "my array is a named object" - so use another level of jsonb_set around the array update code. Have you understood the approaches in the linked answers, and tried to apply them to your situation? If yes, please show us your attempt and how it is not working.


I'd need help with how to preserve outer parts of json (so Id and Elements nodes)

Use jsonb_set on the data with the result of your array expression:
UPDATE table
SET data = jsonb_set(
  data,
  '{Elements}',
  jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.Elements[*] ?(@.ElementId<>1)') || '{"ElementId": 1, "IsEnabled": false, "ProductName": "Name"}'::jsonb
)
WHERE …

